# Which function is responsible for class object initialization at global scope in C++?

Tags: c++, libc

I'm trying to know more about global scope object initialization in c++. For a `class/struct` object at global scope, which function is responsible for it's initialization?

Consider the following example:

```
#include <iostream>

struct foo {
  foo() {
    std::cout << "foo's constructor" << std::endl;
  }
};

foo bar;

int main() {
  std::cout << "main" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

I know that the output will be:

```
foo's constructor
main
```

What I do not understand is why? Which function is responsible for global object initialization (like `int main` is called by `__libc_start_main`)?

Also what kind of initialization is it (static or dynamic)? From what I think it is dynamic initialization.

Comment: Compiler specific. And it's static.

Answer (score 3):

> Which function is responsible for global object initialization

The standard does not specify that.

It only specifies that they be initialized before `main()` is called. An implementation is free to choose whatever mechanism to accomplish that.

> Also what kind of initialization is it (static or dynamic)?

It's not clear what you trying to imply here. It is static initialization. However, all static initializations are divided into:

1. Zero initialization.
2. Constant initilaization.
3. Dynamic initialization.

In your case, it is dynamic initialization.

If you had,

```
int var1;
```

it will be zero initialized.

If you had

```
int var2 = 10;
```

it will be constant initialized.

If you had

```
int var3 = someFunction();
```

it will most likely be initialized using dynamic initialization.

Comment: How is the class object called if there is no function taking care of it?

Comment: Who says code has to be called from a function? Set a breakpoint in your `foo` initializer to see what the stack trace looks like in your compiler.

Comment: Can these class objects be tampered with at runtime? For example, running these objects on another thread?

Comment: @Rohit, no, they can't. All static initialization is completed before `main` is executed. A new thread can start only after `main` starts executing.

Comment: @tadman I checked the stack and saw a call from `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)`. Searching about this function online (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37108163/purpose-of-static-initialization-and-destruction-and-global-sub-i-main-functio?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)) made me understand that this is indeed the function that initializes class constructors (please correct me if I'm wrong). So I think these constructors are also called by a function.

Comment: @Rohit, An implementation is free to chose whichever mechanism works for them to make those calls. What one implementation does has no bearing on what another implementation does. I am not familiar with compiler implementations to be able comment any further than that.

Comment: That's just a compiler convention, not a hard and fast rule. Different compilers might do this different ways. There's nothing in the standard that says precisely how it has to be executed.