# What is _GLOBAL__sub_I_main? And why does it take too much time when OpenMP is used?

Tags: c++, linux, parallel-processing, openmp, profiling

I am trying to parallelize my merge sort code using openMP. I added #pragma omp task before the recursive calls. Then I used the gprof tool to measure my time. I saw that, the parallelization worked, because the time of parallel merge was less.
Let me show the results.
For serial:

```
%time    self  children called     name
83.3    0.15    0.00 1468946       merge(int**, int, int, int, int)
```

For parallel:

```
%time    self  children called     name
56.0    0.14    0.00 1468946       merge(int**, int, int, int, int)
```

Thus I thought it worked. However when I compare the overall time for the whole program, the parallel one takes more time. When I looked at the gprof file again I saw that the parallel one takes more time for `_GLOBAL__sub_I_main` and `__libc_csu_init`. I don't really know that they are but they don't take much time in the serial one.

Serial one:

```
 index % time    self  children    called     name
                0.00    0.00       1/1           __libc_csu_init [28]
[12]     0.0    0.00    0.00       1         _GLOBAL__sub_I_main [12]
                0.00    0.00       1/1           __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int) [13]
-----------------------------------------------
                0.00    0.00       1/1           _GLOBAL__sub_I_main [12]
[13]     0.0    0.00    0.00       1         __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int) [13]
-----------------------------------------------
```

Parallel one:

```
index % time    self  children    called     name
                0.03    0.15       1/1           __libc_csu_init [2]
[1]     73.3    0.03    0.15       1         _GLOBAL__sub_I_main [1]
                0.02    0.13 2937892/3068963     merge(int**, int, int, int, int)
                0.00    0.00       1/1           __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int) [15]
-----------------------------------------------
                                                 <spontaneous>
[2]     73.3    0.00    0.18                 __libc_csu_init [2]
                0.03    0.15       1/1           _GLOBAL__sub_I_main [1]
-----------------------------------------------
```

I am firstly asking what are these? And then asking why do they take this much time in the parallel code?

Thank you

Comment: Well, they appear to be causing data races in the parallel version. Not sure *exactly* what they are, or why it's happening - maybe some of your code would help. From the names, though, they appear to be system-level routines that initialize/setup process(or) conditions.

Comment: Google finds https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37108163/purpose-of-static-initialization-and-destruction-and-global-sub-i-main-functio/37113229

Comment: When asking a question like this, please give more environment details. You know all about your machine, but we do not. So OS, CPU architecture, compiler are all relevant pieces of information...